# jquery Autocomplete widget passing source parameters

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I use the jquery Autocomplete widget. Now I want to activate several controls with this Autocomplete widget:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label id="lbl0">City:</label><br />
    <input id="txt0" style="width: 25%;">
    <br /><br />
    <label id="lbl1">Fruit:</label><br />
    <input id="txt1" style="width: 25%;">
    <br /><br />
    <label id="lbl99">City:</label><br />
    <input id="txt99" style="width: 25%;">
    <br /><br />
    <label id="lbl100">Fruit:</label><br />
    <input id="txt100" style="width: 25%;">
</div>
```

For each control a definition is made what data to use:

```
// the sources we want to use (cities and fruits):
var sourceToUse = ['cities', 'fruits'];
```

A JavaScript loops through the definitions and populates the controls accordingly. In this example the definitions are put in an array named “sourceToUse” (in reality the definitions are retrieved from a database):

```
    $(function () {
       // the sources we want to use (cities and fruits):
       var sourceToUse = ['cities', 'fruits'];
       // populate the controls accordingly using a loop
       for (var i = 0; i <= sourceToUse.length; i++) {
            $("#txt" + i).autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) { fSource(request, response, sourceToUse[i]) },
                    autoFocus: true,
                    delay: 500
            });
       }
       // populate without a loop
       $("#txt99").autocomplete({ source: function (request, response) { fSource(request, response, 'cities') } });
       $("#txt100").autocomplete({ source: function (request, response) { fSource(request, response, 'fruits') } });
   });
```

Function to pass the parameter value to:

```
function fSource(request, response, sourceChosen) {
            // several sources to retrieve from (in a database)
            var cities = ["CAEN", "CALAIS", "CANNES", "CHAMPIGNY-SUR-MARNE", "CLERMOND-FERRAND"];
            var fruits = ["APPLE", "APRICOT", "ADVOCADO", "BLACKBERRY", "BLUEBERRY", ];
            var sourceToUse = [];
            var sourceToReturn = [];
            // a source is chosen to get its data from
            switch (sourceChosen) {
                case 'cities':
                    sourceToUse = cities;
                    break;
                case 'fruits':
                    sourceToUse = fruits;
                    break;
            }
            // return from the source chosen only that what has been asked for
            $.each(sourceToUse, function (index, value) {
                if (value.substring(0, request.term.length) == request.term) {
                    if ($.inArray(value, sourceToReturn) == -1) {
                        sourceToReturn.push(value);
                    }
                }
            });
            response(sourceToReturn);
        }
```

On using a loop the value for parameter "sourceChosen" is not passed through to function “fSource”. In this example the data is taken from an array “cities” or “fruits”. (in reality the data is retrieved from a database)  If I assign a value directly it works. Any idea why passing parameters does not work?

See this Plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/wEy5HC4tv4m1hwoQOheZ